# Choose which oci.dll use with qsqloci plugin

Tags: oracle, qt, dll

I'd like to be able to choose which oci.dll the Qt plugin is using, the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/sql-driver.html#qoci-for-the-oracle-call-interface-oci) states:

> When you run your application you will
>   also need to add the oci.dll  path to
>   your PATH environment variable: set
>   `PATH=%PATH%;c:\oracle\bin`

Is there another way than changing the `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

You can subkey of the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`. See [Adding a Application specific paths, so it works from the command line in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114618/adding-a-application-specific-paths-so-it-works-from-the-command-line-in-windows/3114674#3114674) and [Use registry to startup a program, and also change the current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822951/use-registry-to-startup-a-program-and-also-change-the-current-working-directory/) for details and other ways.

Comment: Thanks, but for portability I'd rather not use the Windows registry.

Comment: Changing of environment variable is platform dependent. If you explain how you application will be started, I can suggest you another ways, but you wrote too little information in your question.